# What does it mean for an integral's differential to be raised to a power, like e.g. $d^3r$ or $d^3u$?

Tags: conventions, notation, spacetime-dimensions, integration

I was reading Zwelfel's book on reactor physics and saw the following notation:

> [image]

Notice that the differential of the integral is raised to the third power.

What is the meaning of this notation?  Are they trying to imply a volume integral here?  How would I convert this to a Riemann sum?

Comment: $\mathrm{d}^3u = \mathrm{d}v_x\, \mathrm{d}v_y\, \mathrm{d}v_z$.  If you have trouble with that notation, you might be jumping into the deep end rather than walking in from the shoreline.  You will next have to deal with $\mathrm{d}^3u = u^2\mathrm{d}u\,\mathrm{d}\Omega$.  Do you have problems with that one?

Comment: @garyp nice metaphor

Comment: Actually, I do. I assume this is some sort of coordinate system change or something? Do you have any insight?

Comment: The latter expression is the volume element in spherical coordinates, while the former is in Cartesian coordinate.  $\mathrm{d}\Omega$ is a differential "volume" of solid angle:  $\mathrm{d}\Omega = \sin\theta\,\mathrm{d}\theta\,\mathrm{d}\phi$.  I hope that's enough to send you to a book or online course on calculus and analytic geometry.  You really have to back up.

Comment: It's an abuse of notation. The meaning is as explained in the answers below, but note that the whole $dx$ notation is pretty badly explained/justified. Ask yourself if there's really any difference between $\int_0^\pi \sin(x) \, dx$ and $\int_0^\pi \sin(x)$.

Comment: @DanielSank The $dx$ is crucial because if, for example, $d(x^2)=2xdx$ were used instead, it would be a completely different integral. You can no more omit a $dx$ in an integral than you can in a derivative.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The notation $\mathrm d^3r$, often also $\mathrm d^3\mathbf r$, is generally understood to indicate a three-dimensional volume integral, as you correctly surmise. If $\mathbf r=(x,y,z)$ then you could also denote that as $\mathrm dx\,\mathrm dy\,\mathrm dz$, or as $\mathrm dV$ if it is clear what the integration variable is.

The notation $\mathrm d^3\mathbf r$ is more compact and it does a better job at specifying exactly what the integration variable is and what sort of integral is being taken; this is very useful in places where the page is already busy enough, like, say,

[image]

where directly specifying the components of $\vec k$ would (i) make the formula much, much longer, and (ii) actually make the text *less* readable.

In addition to this, it is very common for authors to simply drop the superscript and use notation like $\mathrm d\mathbf r$ when it's clear that it can only be a volume integral ([example](http://arxiv.org/abs/1507.00011)), and even mix both notations, introducing superscripts when required to indicate the dimensionality of the integral ([example](http://arxiv.org/abs/1309.4765)).

Comment: I don't see why the $\textbf{r}$ should be bold (I know many textbooks are so). After all, $d\,\textrm{(whatever)}$ is shorthand (actually long-hand) for a measure $m$, which is generally a number.

Comment: @Gennaro It's a matter of taste. I'm not saying it *should* be bold, I'm saying it *can* be bold, and the OP should be prepared for both notations. (Personally, I find that bold makes sense if the variable is normally bold, because the differential is shorthand for marking the integration variable (and not really indicating the measure; if that's in question then you do things like $\mathrm d\mu(\mathbf r)$) so it makes sense to just put in the variable as is, and because the unbolded version is typically a different quantity. But again, it's exclusively a matter of taste.)

Comment: In case anyone's curious, that example is Eq. I.4.4 from A. Zee's Quantum Field Theory in a Nutshell.

Answer (score 1):

I would normaly understand an Integral $\int d^3\mathbf{r}$
 as a volume integral over the whole space $ \mathbb{R}_3$, where I would understand the bold r there as $\vec{r}$ . I have also seen $\int d^3 \vec{r}$ meaning the same volume integral over $ \mathbb{R}_3$. Or even $\int d~ \vec{r}$ with the superscript dropped (I do not like this one but I have seen it in literature). All the previous expressions are coordinate independent and $\vec{r}$ or bold $\mathbf{r}$ denote the general location vector.

A differential $dr$ without a vector arrow or without the superscript or not in bold is usally (at least in physics) meant as a differential concerning the radius in spherical coordinates. So the volume integral is commonly written as:

$\int d^3 \vec{r} \equiv \int d~ \vec{r} \equiv \int d^3\mathbf{r} = \int_{-\infty }^{+\infty }\int_{-\infty }^{+\infty }\int_{-\infty }^{+\infty }dxdydz=\int_{0 }^{2\pi }\int_{0 }^{\pi }\int_{0 }^{\infty }r^2 \sin(\theta)d\phi d\theta dr $.

Where the last two equalities are in cartesian and spherical coordinates respectively.

Comment: I think that the value of the above answer is that if you are reading such things, be ready for any notation that might describe volume, surface, line, or whatever dimension of integrals.  A lot of ways to say the same thing.